# How to increase the exponents using loops?

Tags: c++, loops

I want to increase the exponents using loop. For example, X is the number where the exponents started, Y is the number of exponents  ended. And Z is the base number.
So if the input is:

> X=1 Y=6 Z=2

The output will be

> 2 4 6 8 16 32 64

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    int x,y,z;

    cout<<"X = ";
    cin>>x;

    cout<<"Y = ";
    cin>>y;

    cout<<"Z = ";
    cin>>z;

    for(z=z;z<=z;z){

        for(x=x;x<=y;x++){

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That is what i can do. What should i do in the loop section?

Comment: Please test my answer and approve it when you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the exponent from the lower bound (x) to the upper bound (y), and perform the operation z^n where (n >= x and n <= y). See my code below, I renamed x to start, y to finish and z to base, for readability. Don't forget to include math.h.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int start, finish, base;

    cout << "Start: ";
    cin >> start;
    cout << "Finish: ";
    cin >> finish;
    cout << "Base: ";
    cin >> base;

    // start at lower bound, increase n by 1
    // until n is equal to upper bound
    for(int n = start; n <= finish; n++) {
        cout << base << "^" << n << " = " << pow(base, n) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The former solutions have the drawback to calculate `pow(base, exponent)` at each iteration.
Much less operations are obtained by calculating the result iteratively

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    int first, last, base;

    cout << "first = ";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "last = ";
    cin >> last;
    cout << "base = ";
    cin >> base;


    int result = pow (base, first);

    for(int exponent = first; exponent <= last; ++exponent){
        cout << base << "^" << exponent << " = " << result << "\n";
        result *= base;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should limit the exponent according to your datatype in order to prevent overflow, or use a larger type.

Comment: @Dan It is a little exercise. I just wanted to illustrate how to limit the number of operations. Changing the data type does not prevent overflow, and limiting the value of exponent is another exercise

Comment: All good, not having a dig, just pointing it out, wasn't sure if you where aware

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
    int pow_num = pow(z,i); // This is what you have to do.
}
```

Also note that for larger value of `y` you will see [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). You have to take care of that.